# Is it possible that rebuild operation won't start for any repaired keyspaces?

Tags: cassandra

I've a very interesting question, is it possible that cassandra won't start rebuild process for any repaired keyspace? if we have few in unrepaired state using this option: nodetool rebuild --DATACENTER -ks KEYSPACE_NAME.

We saw the strange experiment yesterday, if there are few unrepaired keyspaces into the our cluster, and we've decided to change for example replication strategy for some keyspace which have been already repaired and using this command: nodetool rebuild --DATACENTER -ks KEYSPACE_NAME - this command fell with: Unable to find sufficient sources for streaming range, but if we start the command without --DATECENTER: nodetool rebuild -ks KEYSPACE_NAME - data will be appear on the all new nodes, instead only one, can we use this approach or is it bad idea ?.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense because it's missing crucial details. Please update it with (1) keyspace definition, (2) full `nodetool rebuild` command you're running, (3) output of `nodetool status`, (4) full error message, (5) full stack trace, and (6) Cassandra version. Cheers!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How many datacenters are in your cluster, and what are their names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rebuild operation doesn't have any relation to repairs.

`nodetool rebuild` will populate data for token ranges on a node depending on whether the data has been streamed before or not (through bootstrap or rebuild).

Cassandra stores the "state" of token ranges of a node in the `system.available_ranges` table. If a node has been bootstrapped or rebuilt successfully, it will store the available ranges for each keyspace so it knows which data it can serve for read requests.

Furthermore, this error:

```
Unable to find sufficient sources for streaming range
```

would have been due to you removing the source DC from replication so Cassandra could not rebuild the new DC because there are no longer any replicas in the source DC you specified.

When you removed the source DC from the `rebuild` command, it just streamed the data from the other nodes in the new DC which is bad because the DC does not have data, by definition it is new.

In any case, your "experiment" is invalid. Repair is not a recommended way to transfer data to a new node. If it was, we wouldn't have a need for `rebuild`.

Think of your situation where you have 2 DCs with 3 replicas in each DC. This means a total of 6 replicas (2 DCs x 3 replicas). Repair is very expensive because it compares the data between 6 replicas to determine which data is missing on the node where you ran it.

Since the node is new, we already know it doesn't have data so doing the comparison with the 5 other replicas in the cluster is a waste of resources. All that is required is to request the data from another replica which is exactly what `rebuild` is designed to do. Cheers!

Comment: Eric thanks so much for your advanced explanation, it's very useful and helpful information, but i still can't understand few things, I've decided to re-done my experiment, kill datacenter2 from ring via decommission on each node, clean all the nodes from datacenter2 and remove all data from cassandra /data directories, then altered all needed keyspaces (3 system + 2 user keyspaces) and remove any information about datacenter2

Comment: Then i've done repair --full for each keyspace, then re-added all 3 nodes for datacenter2 (with auto_bootstrap: false) option in my cassandra.yaml, then I've ALTERED again with datacenter2 for (3 system + 2 user keyspaces) and then i tried to rebuild for single keyspace only, i've chosen for system_auth and again i saw this:
nodetool -h localhost -u admin -pw my_password rebuild --datacenter1 -ks system_auth
nodetool: Unable to find sufficient sources for streaming range Full(/192.168.1.141:7000,(9143760283360780305,-9110058574097929690]) in keyspace system_auth

Comment: I checked the cassandra schema via nodetool describecluster and it the same for each node, and in the debug.log i didn't find any interesting information or error or exception.

Comment: maybe is it possible that cassandra can keep any inrormation about previous datacenter2 ? and it must be clean before i will try to re-add with the same name as the new

Comment: You can't run a `rebuild` on `system_auth` because you need it to run `nodetool`. The correct procedure is to repair the it when you change its replication. Cheers!

Comment: Eric good morning! what did you mean? when you wrote about repair instead rebuild, my question is: "is it necessary to run nodetool rebuild command for: system_auth, system_traces and system_distributed or I need rebuild only for user keyspaces when I plan to run rebuild in the future"

Comment: You need to authenticate to run the `rebuild` command so you need to run a repair every time you alter the replication for `system_auth`. Cheers!

Comment: Eric thanks for answers, Cheers!